# The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have configured SharePoint Foundation 2013 farm and created Search Service Application through the Central Administration Configuration Wizard by deleting the previous created Search Service Application because that was stuck in `'Paused For : External Request'` and we were not able to resume the same.

Now, Search service Application starts appearing in list of Service Applications, However, when I click on Search Service Application I am getting below error.

> The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component 'GUID' in search application 'Search Service Application' is in a good state and try again.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of things to check.

**Solution # 1** simply change the application pool to use SharePoint Web Services System for search service applications and check.

1. Go IIS
2. In IIS > Expand server > Expand sites > Expand “SharePoint Web Services
3. Now check all the GUID 1 by 1 in content view unless you find searchadmin.svc and searchservice.svc
4. Right click GUID go to advance settings
5. Change the application to “SharePoint Web Services” > Click OK

**Solution # 2**Enable the timer job and do IIS reset:

1. Run below PS command to enable the service.
2. Enable-SPTimerJob job-application-server-admin-service
3. Result ==> IsDisabled: False
4. Do Net Stop sptimerv4
5. Do Net start sptimerv4
6. Do iisreset

Solution 3

Ensure the account has full control permissions on the Search service application and IIS account used by this service application

1. Open Central Admin  > Select Security > Select “Configure service accounts”
2. Select the search service application
3. For “select account for this component” Select a account which has full permission

[SharePoint Server: "The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28772.sharepoint-server-the-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-machine-that-hosts-the-administration-component.aspx)

Comment: Checked all these settings, but no luck.

I had deleted the previous search service application which was stuck in 'paused for:external request' state and re-created this new search service application through Configuration wizard in SharePoint Foundation 2013 and this is causing above problem.

Comment: how many search application you have now

Comment: Only One Search Service Application that I am having in the Farm.

Answer (score 3):

You should run the psconfiguration wizard once and that should definitely solve your problem.

Comment: This worked for me, why i never think of this!

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me: moving the SearchAdministrationComponent back and forth

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cls


$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
$admin = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent -SearchApplication $ssa
$admin | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent -SearchServiceInstance SERVERNAME -Force
```