# The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component"

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, central-administration

I have a problem with all Search Service Applications on my server. Every search application has Administrative status:

> "The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts
>   the administration component. Verify that the administration component
>   '{GUID}' in search application '{Search Service Application Name}' is
>   in a good state and try again."

I've tried to resolve this problem by solution presented in post: [The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169793/the-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-machine-that-hosts-the-administ)

I've also tried to reset timer job. Moreover, I've tried to create new Search application, but when I was trying to Active new topology i got the same error.

Update: 
I created a new Search Service Application through the Central Administration. The fresh Search Service Application still has the same Administrative error status.

I also found out that, even if I create new topology with new components, the SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance is empty (status is "Online", but it has 0 components). 
[image: Search Administration]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the problem. I used a SharePoint Repair tool (In "Program and Features" -> "Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013" -> "Change" -> "Repair"). Previous search service applications are working now.